# how to use multiple controller in a single view(jsp) file

Tags: java, spring, jsp, model-view-controller

I have a single jsp page, `mypage.jsp` . this has 2 tabs- firsttab and secondtab. Each of these tabs have their own forms.

Each tab has to handled by separate controller, say firsttab is handled by `firsttabcontroller` and secondtab is handled by `secondtabcontroller`.

Now if i submit a form in firsttab there may be  chance that content in secondtab is altered.
and the same effects can be expected with changes in secondtab affecting firsttab content.

**Everytime i make a request to any controller the very same page- `mypage.jsp`  should be rendered.**

so the problem is handling multiple forms/tabs mapped to different controllers from the same view.

How to achieve this?
I looked into some similar questions but none of them gave me satisfactory answers.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do this using AJAX. You can populate the tabs with HTML requested from the two different controller URLs.

This might look like the following where the tab you're populating has a div with id mytab.

```
$.get('<spring:url value='/myurl'/>', function(data) {
  $('#mytab').html(data);
});
```

When you submit the form in tab 1 you just need to trigger a GET to the controller which populates tab 2 to refresh the contents.